# in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have excel **template** that has multiple sheets with US States `(MTHLY-CA...etc)`

[image]

I also have a **dataframe** that has columns `StateID` and `premiumtest`

[image]

The idea is to loop through worksheet names and compare it to column StateID in a dataframe.  And if states matches then write `premiumtest` value into particular cell in a template.

```
import openpyxl
# getting workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'\server\user\Python\Template.xlsx')
# looping through worksheets
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
     sheetnames = sheet
     print(sheetnames)


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if any(x in 'MTHLY-'+ row[0] for x in sheetnames): #[0]is the index for column StateID            
    # Then write premiumtest into cell 1
```

But I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    if any(x in 'MTHLY-'+ row[0] for x in sheetnames):  #
  File "x:\Documents\Python\Treaty Year Report\TreatyYearReport3 - Copy.py", line 68, in <genexpr>
    if any(x in 'MTHLY-'+ row[0] for x in sheetnames):  # 
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

print(sheetnames): .

[image: sheetnames]

Comment: The intent is to compare x (worksheet names) to row[0] (states in df). So do I need to convert tuple to list?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python.

Comment: I suppose the string (sheet name) you're looking for can be obtained as `sheet.title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get your code

```py
any(x in 'MTHLY-'+ row[0] for x in sheetnames)
```

running properly, you could obtain the sheets names as

```py
sheetnames = [sheet.title for sheet in wb.worksheets]
```

that would basically replace your current for loop

```
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
     sheetnames = sheet
     print(sheetnames)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a single worksheet object to a string. This is the issue. In the code below you're looping through each sheet then overritting the `sheetnames` variable.

```
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
   sheetnames = sheet
   print(sheetnames)
```

You are looking to get is a list of the `worksheet.title` so more something like this:

```
sheetnames = [sheet.title for sheet in wb.worksheets]
```

Comment: 4 seconds faster :)

Comment: Dang, beat me to it +1 for you from me

Comment: and vice versa +1 since your answer is (almost) exactly the same ;-)